# How do I merge coverage reports of independent test runs

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, jacoco, cobertura, clover

In our (grails 2.x) projects, we often have plugins, that come with their own unit tests, but are accompanied by testapps, which include the plugin inline, and run functional and integration tests.

To run the tests, we first run the unit tests on the plugin project, and then run the integration and functional tests on the test application.

I would like to start using code coverage metrics, but I need my data to be representative of all the tests that are running, not just unit tests that come embedded in the plugin source tree.

I have not yet chosen a particular code coverage solution, so this is a free variable that could help solve the issue.

Any help or insight appreciated